# What does Keras progress bar show?

Tags: python, keras

How is the progress bar shown when fitting a model and when evaluating its performance? I know how to make it visible, but what is it based on?

I made a simple `Sequential` model with a few layers, compiled and started to train:

```
# x.shape: (3270, n)
# y.shape: (3270, 1)
model.fit(x, y, epochs=20, batch_size=300)
```

If I've read the documentation right, this is what ought to happen internally: the data is iterated through such that an optimisation step considers only the batch-size-amount of data, for every batch until the data set is exhausted. Then begins the next epoch.

For the large batch sizes the progress bar of epochs remains fixed, seems like it's the size of the batch to the whole training data:

```
 300/3270 [=>............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4178 - acc: 0.8433
3270/3270 [==============================] - 0s 9us/step - loss: 0.3813 - acc: 0.8593
Epoch 17/20
```

But for smaller sizes there appears to be more and a varying amount of bars and they actually display some movement.

```
  30/3270 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5154 - acc: 0.8333
1770/3270 [===============>..............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3560 - acc: 0.8621
3270/3270 [==============================] - 0s 29us/step - loss: 0.3631 - acc: 0.8618
Epoch 19/20

  30/3270 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3360 - acc: 0.8667
1620/3270 [=============>................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3473 - acc: 0.8667
3120/3270 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3599 - acc: 0.8622
3270/3270 [==============================] - 0s 33us/step - loss: 0.3592 - acc: 0.8621
Epoch 20/20
```

I didn't find information on exactly what are these bars showing. So I'd appreciate any insight.

Comment: In what environment do you use and retrieve the progress bar? The bar is designed to change in-ligne. So at the end of the traning you'll see only one bar per epoch(in the ideal case). Depending on your console sometimes the progress bar starts a new line. (Sometimes it even starts a new line continously)

Comment: @dennis-ec I'm sorry I don't quite get your question as I'm very new to Keras. But to generally tell you about my environment, it's Python 3.5 x64 running on PyCharm. Keras is using TensorFlow. I'm simply printing the progress bar with the `model.fit(verbose=1)`.

Comment: @dennis-ec Oh! Do you mean that it should print and *change* the progress bar on the command line? Hmm.. That could be a quirk of PyCharm then.

Comment: Yes. Try this: In pycharm there is a build in console and the command to run the script directly. In the bottom of your program there ale the tabs Run and Terminal. Terminal is a normal console where you can type `python your_script.py` if you rght click on the tab of your program in the upper section of Pycharm you can also run your program in the run section. The progress bar will show different behaviour.

Comment: @dennis-ec Yep, terminal works! A quick way to the terminal is alt+F12.

Comment: Was this the full answer of you question or is there anything else?

Comment: @dennis-ec I think so. This makes the progress bar actually make sense. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments: The progress bar shows the progress of each epoch and is designed to update in-line till the end of epoch. Normally then, the progress bar is full and a new progress bar is started for the next epoch.

Sometimes, depending in which terminal you start your program, the progress bar will start a new line. A good example is Pycharm where you can run your python script in terminal or in the run tab which are both at the bottom of the program.
Here the progress bar will behave differently but normally the terminal tab show the normal and desired behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same doubt about the progress bar and found this:

**Example (1)**
[image: Model 1 Progress Bar]

The epoch is straightforward! In my model I defined that the Number of Epochs was 6.

- The first part (Epoch 2/6): Shows that the model had processed all the training examples twice.

But What is the 81/81 part of the progress bar?

[image: Training set 1]

- The second part (81/81): Shows the progress of the fitting process in each epoch (steps per epoch). My training set has 2569 examples, and my batch_size was 32. Then 23262/32 ~81

**Example (2)**
[image: Model 2 Progress Bar]

Number of Epochs was 80.

- The first part (Epoch x/80): Shows that the model had processed all the training examples x times.

And again, Why is the 30/30 number shown in the progress bar?

[image: Training set 2]

- The second part (30/30): Comes from:  training set has 2569 examples, and my batch_size was 100. Then:
  `ceil(2935/100) = 30`